# method categories does not exist. laravel

Tags: laravel-5.4

What is this error?

> method categories does not exist. laravel

ArticleController.php

```
public function store(ArticleRequest $request)
{
    $imagesUrl = $this->uploadImages($request->file('images'));
    auth()->user()->article()->create(array_merge($request->all(), ['images' => $imagesUrl]));
    $request->categories()->attach(request('category'));
    return redirect(route('articles.index'));
}
```

Article.php

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

Category.php

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access `categories` relation in request. You need to add it to your model. Change code to this:

```php
$article = auth()->user()->article()->create(array_merge($request->all(), ['images' => $imagesUrl]));
$article->categories()->attach(request('category'));
```